# Nesting existing collection inside object

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I'm trying to configure filter mutates properly for a logastash configuration file, but I fail.

1. I have a tags array which comes from SQL as a string like this:

   `"lunch | mellanmål | middag"`
2. I configure `mutate` to split it into collection like this:

   `mutate { split => ["meal_type_tags", " | "] }`
3. I'm getting an index with an expected collection:

   `"meal_type_tags" : ["lunch", "mellanmål","middag"]`
4. I'm trying rename to nest it inside a new `tags` object by adding another mutate:

   `mutate { rename => "meal_type_tags" => "[tags][meal_type]"}`

**My expected index is:**

```
"tags": { 
        "meal_type" : 
                        [
                            "lunch", 
                            "mellanmål"
                            "middag"
                        ] 
    }
```

**...but I get this instead:**

```
"tags" : [
            [
              "meal_type",
              [
                "middag",
                "lunch"
              ]
            ]
          ]
```

Comment: Perhaps it should be `rename => {"meal_type_tags" => "[tags][meal_type]"}}` (missing `{}`)? Also `tags` already exists and is an array, perhaps the issue comes from that.

Comment: @baudsp what tags array exist? Also you're suggesting unopened bracket

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why but it just wouldn't work if I tried rename to `tags`. I changed to `recipe_tags` and it worked I expected. Maybe @baudsp know more, as the solution was inspired by his comment.

Comment: I think it might coming from that logstash add a `tags` field by default to all events, so it might not be possible to modify that field outside of the `add_tag` option. Just an hypotheses.